# Bootstrap: justify-content-{} and navbar classes in the same nav element

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

Hope someone can help me out with the following and I do apologize if the topic has been discussed before but I haven't found anything. I'm starting with bootstrap and particularly with the navbars. If I'm not wrong navbar class applies the flex value and converts into flex-items its childs. Why , then, when I apply the class justify-content-xx the elements remain on the same position?. Thanks in advance.

```html
<nav class="container navbar navbar-expand-md justify-content-lg-end navbar-light bg-light">
  <span class="navbar-brand">RANDOM NAME</span>

  <div class="navbar-text">SOME RANDOM TEXT </div> 
  
  <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNav2">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse px-10" id="myNav2">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link04</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link05</a></li>
      <li class="nav-item"><a href="#" class="nav-link">Link06</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  
</nav>
```

Comment: The `navbar-collapse` class you put on that inner div element applies `flex-grow: 1;` - so that element already fills the rest of the remaining space. (Easy to see if you apply an outline to it, or simply inspect it using your browser dev tools.) And because your flex items cover the _whole_ width of their flex parent already, "justifying" the content to the left, right or center, always gets the same result. There simply is no space _between_ the elements here to begin with. Apply `flex-grow: 0` to your collapsible element, then you will get the desired result.